# php query not working without giveing any error

Tags: php, sql

i am having issues with the query below its showing success with no error but not inserting to the database

here is my code

```
public function uploadImg($table, $imageurl){
        //path to tore the uploaded images
        $target = "../images/" .basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        //echo $target;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ($imageurl) values('$target')";
        $q = $this->DBcon->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute();


        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
            echo "uploaded successfully";
        }else{
            echo "error uploading";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do u assign value to `$imageurl` ?

Comment: And this will not show any error because you are not showing them

Comment: what's the value of the `prepare` statement without using the [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) ??

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile "where do u assign value to $imageurl" ,, here `uploadImg($table, $imageurl)`

Comment: @Imm why not to print your error and see ? `$q->errorInfo()`

Comment: @hassan isn't he supposed to assign value to the `imageurl` after successfully moved the file to the upload directory?

Comment: @Imm you not helping if you not gonna take part in the comments, we don't wanna assume we wanna give direct straight answers

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile logically your are right :-)

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$sql = "insert into " . $table . " set " . $imageurl . "=" . $target;
```

if `$tabel` and `$imageurl` exists, a record will be created. And if `$target` has a string, it will be registered in the field which is represented by $`imageurl`.

Answer (score -2):

fixed

simply change your query from

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ($imageurl) values('$target')";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ('$imageurl') values('$target')";
```